# resize ckeditor for responsive design

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor on a responsive design, and I cannot get the height to work. The following code with height define works to resize the text area to 100%, which overflows the containing div.

```
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'article', {
            toolbar: [
                { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic' ] },
                { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Blockquote' ] },
                { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink' ] },
                { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image' ] }
            ],
            uiColor: '#f9fafb',
            height: '100%'
        });
```

I have found the below code, but I can't figure out where to paste it. I've also tried editing config.js, and following all the documentation on CKEDitor's website. They tell you what to do, but not where to do it.

```
editor.resize( '100%', '350', true );
```

In theory, the "true" will make the height include the entire editor, not just the text area, but I don't know where it belongs.

The div containing the editor uses this CSS:

```
height: -moz-calc(100% - 400px);
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 400px);
height: calc(100% - 400px);
```

Comment: You'll need to tap into the window's `resize` event and do the JavaScript resize there.

Comment: can you give me a clue as to how to do that?

Comment: CKEditor already comes with/requires jQuery, right? If it does, check out the example on jQuery's `.resize()` event: http://api.jquery.com/resize/ you would put the `editor.resize()` in that function, and pass it the new desired pixel width.

Comment: Note that `CKEDITOR.replace` returns `editor` object. You can also find your instance in global `CKEDITOR.instances` object.

Answer (score 19):

In django, I had to set the width to `auto` in the `settings.py` file:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar': None, #You can change this based on your requirements.
    'width': 'auto',

          },
    }
```

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. This is working as expected ! :))

Comment: Works exactly, thank you

Answer (score 8):

if u want to do responsive need to change setting in `config.js`

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {

    config.width = "auto";
    config.height = "auto";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* main.css */
.django-ckeditor-widget {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Find which div has a fixed width and force it's width to `auto`.

```
#cke_description {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Worked for me on `Version 4.4.4`.